# How to extract a given frame from a .gif animation in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I'm trying to figure out how to extract a given frame from an animated-gif, possibly in PIL, in Python.
I'm not able to easily dig this up, and I'm guessing it would take some knowledge of the gif format, something that is not readily understandable to me.
Is there any straightforward way to accomplish this? Do I need to do some custom parsing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> #### Reading Sequences
>
> The GIF loader supports the `seek` and
>   `tell` methods. You can seek to the next
>   frame `(im.seek(im.tell()+1)`, or rewind
>   the file by seeking to the first
>   frame. Random access is not supported.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/format-gif.htm
http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

Comment: Okay, how would I count the frames in the .gif?

Comment: @CMC Apparently the only way is to keep seeking until an exception (`EOFError`) is raised.

Comment: I guess that'll have to suffice. Thanks!